# I am not able to install Tendsa w311m driver ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

I downloaded driver from https://www.tendacn.com/in/download/detail-2536.html.When I make it.It shows me some errors like this.

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.c', needed by 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:232: archscripts] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:389: LINUX] Error 2
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem,is with this adapter.This adapter does not support linux.I bought TP link wifi adapter instead of this tenda w311mi at the same price.